# jQuery or Javascript image viewer for a single image with different sizes?

Tags: javascript

I have a single image. I want to resize that image in a small window. How to stretch an image in a window by making it bigger image and smaller image.

Width and height attributes are not working properly.
I mean how to stretch an image by giving width and height as follows;

```
width=300px;height=300px
again width=600px;height=600px;
and width=900px;height=900px;
and widht=1800px;height=1800px;
```

Comment: Is something like `document.getElementById('middle-logo').style.width = '300px'`  and `document.getElementById('middle-logo').style.height = '300px'` what you are looking for? If yes, do read more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height to `auto` which will keep the ratio respective to the width. Also, HTML attributes don't need the "px" units, that's for CSS.

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="300" height="auto" alt="Some image">
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="600" height="auto" alt="Some image">
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="900" height="auto" alt="Some image">
<img src="someimage.jpg" width="1800" height="auto" alt="Some image">
```

You tagged this javascript. If you wanted to change the size with JavaScript, you would need to reference the image with an id first, and change the attributes after that.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('testimg').width = 500;
  }
</script>

<img id="testimg" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8426/7758832526_cc8f681e48.jpg" height="auto">
```

If you wanted the image to go larger or smaller with the window, like in a pop-up window, set the width to `100%` and leave the height to `auto`. This will make the image conform to its containing element.